# С++ ошибка С3863(тип массива является неназначаемым) visual studio 2017

Tags: c++, массивы, visual-c++, g++

Поясните, пожалуйста, в чем суть ошибки С3863? 
Проект компилируется и работает в g++. Однако при сборке проекта в Visual Studio 2017 компилятор выдает ошибку  С3863 (тип массива является неназначаемым). Это массив указателей на объекты класса SensorData.

```
Серьезность Код Описание    Проект  Файл    Строка  Состояние подавления
Ошибка  C3863   тип массива "SensorData *[quantity]" является неназначаемым data    c:\users\chas\clang\generation.cpp  42
```

Имеется 3 файла: generation.cpp, source.cpp, source.hpp. Код программ:

```
    // ***** generation.cpp *****
#include <ctime> // time_t
#include <cstdio> // sprintf
#include <iostream> //cin cout
#include <cstdlib> // exit success
#include "source.hpp"

using namespace std;

int main (int argc, char* argv[])
{
    cout <<"Программа записи показаний датчиков температуры и влажности в" <<
    " базу данных. Для этого потребуется указать модель, координаты " <<
    "установки и дату установки датчиков.\n";
    cout << "Укажите количество датчиков для внесения в базу данных, " <<
    "либо 0 для выхода.\n";
    int quantity = 0;
    while(true)
    {
        cin >> quantity;
        if(quantity > 0)
            break;
        else if(quantity == 0)
            return EXIT_SUCCESS;
        else
            cout <<"Ошибка! Ввведите положительное число, либо 0.\n";
    }

    SensorData *ptr[quantity];
    int complete = 0; // автозаполнение данных датчиков
    cout << "Требуется автозаполнение данных датчиков (модель, " <<
    "координаты, дата установки)?\n" << "0-да, 1(и др.числа)-нет: ";
    cin >> complete;
    if(!complete)
    {
        for(int i=0; i<quantity; ++i)
        {
            char buffer [6];
            sprintf (buffer, "DHT%d", 11*(i%2+1));
            ptr[i]=new SensorData(buffer, time(NULL)-300000*(i%50+1),
            201600+3152*(i%5), 216000+3517*(i%8));
            ptr[i]->generateMesuares();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        for(int i=0; i<quantity; ++i)
        {
            ptr[i]=new SensorData;
            ptr[i]->setModel();
            ptr[i]->setCoordinates();
            ptr[i]->setDate();
            ptr[i]->generateMesuares();
        }
    }

    while(true)
    {
        cout << "\nСписок датчиков в базе данных: \n";
        int i;
        for(i=0; i<quantity; ++i)
        {
            cout << "№" << i+1 << endl;
            ptr[i]->getInfo();
        }
        int selection;
        while(true)
        {
        cout << "Выберите номер датчика (0-для выхода): ";
        cin >> selection;
        if(selection < 0 || selection > i+1)
            cout << "Выберите снова. \n";
        else
            break;
        }
        if(!selection)
            return EXIT_SUCCESS;
        time_t begin, end;
        while(true)
        {
            cout << "Выберите период измерений: \n";
            cout << "Выбор даты начала периода \n";
            begin = ptr[selection-1]->choiceTime();
            cout << "Выбор даты конца периода \n";
            end = ptr[selection-1]->choiceTime();
            if(begin > end)
                cout <<"Дата начала периода позже даты окончания.\n";
            else
                break;
        }
        while(true)
        {
            int choice = 0;
            while(true)
            {
                cout << "Выберите результат обработки данных: \n";
                cout << "1 - минимальное значение;\n";
                cout << "2 - среднее значение;\n";
                cout << "3 - максимальное значение;\n";
                cout << "4 - три предыдущих параметра;\n";
                cout << "0 - вернуться к списку датчиков.\n";
                cin >> choice;
                if(choice < 0 || choice > 4)
                    cout << "Выберите снова. \n";
                else
                    break;
            }
            if(!choice)
                break;
            else
                switch(choice)
                {
                    case 1:
                        ptr[selection-1]->getMinMeasure(begin, end);
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        ptr[selection-1]->getMiddleMeasure(begin, end);
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        ptr[selection-1]->getMaxMeasure(begin, end);
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        ptr[selection-1]->getMinMeasure(begin, end);
                        ptr[selection-1]->getMiddleMeasure(begin, end);
                        ptr[selection-1]->getMaxMeasure(begin, end);
                        break;
                }
        }
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

// *****source.hpp

#ifndef SOURCE_HPP
#define SOURCE_HPP
#include <ctime> // time_t
#include <vector> // vector
#include <string> // string
using namespace std;

class Measures
{
public:
    Measures();
    Measures(time_t timeAndDate, float temperatureMeasure, 
    float humidityMeasure);
    void getMeasures();
    time_t dateAndTime;
    float temperature;
    float humidity;
};

class Sensor
{
public:
    Sensor();
    Sensor(const char *str, time_t timeAndDate, int latLocation,
    int longLocation);
    void setModel();
    void setCoordinates();
    time_t conversionTime();
    void setDate();
    void getInfo();
    time_t getInstallDate();
private:
    string model; // модель
    int latitude; // место установки широта, секунды
    int longitude; // место установки долгота, секунды
    time_t installationDate; // дата установки
};

class SensorData : public Sensor
{
public:
    SensorData(){};
    SensorData(const char *str, time_t timeAndDate, int latLocation,
    int longLocation) : Sensor(str, timeAndDate, latLocation, longLocation){};
    vector<Measures> measures_;
    void generateMesuares();
    vector<Measures>::iterator searchIterator(Measures *startPtr,
    time_t timeLimit);
    //выбор времени из диапазона времени измерений
    time_t choiceTime();
    vector<Measures>::iterator searchIterator(vector<Measures>::iterator p,
    time_t timeLimit);
    //печатаем максимальное T и H за указанный период
    void getMaxMeasure(time_t timeBegin, time_t timeEnd);
    //печатаем минимальное T и H за указанный период
    void getMinMeasure(time_t timeBegin, time_t timeEnd);
    //печатаем среднее T и H за указанный период
    void getMiddleMeasure(time_t timeBegin, time_t timeEnd);
};
#endif // SOURCE_HPP

далее реализации методов в source.cpp
```

Вопрос: как же сделать так, чтобы при скомпиляции не появлялась ошибка С3863, и не избавляться от массива? На мой взгляд в нем весь смысл автоматизации программы. И пожалуйста поясните, почему и зачем VS так критически относится к подобным массивам?

Comment: C/C++ не разрешает массивы, у которых размер определяется на этапе выполнения. Размер массива должен быть константным выражением, которое вычисляется на этапе компиляции. Не знаю почему g++ пропускает такую грубую ошибку, видимо это баг именно g++. А VC++ правильно выдает ошибку компиляции.

Comment: @freim, это не баг, а расширение от GCC - https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Variable-Length.html, и оно отключаемо - https://stackoverflow.com/a/17899408/5000805

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну, раз вы используете векторы - я бы заменил

```
SensorData *ptr[quantity];
```

на

```
vector<SensorData*> ptr(quantity);
```

По сути этого достаточно...

Comment: Ошибки исчезли!!

Comment: - Аааа!!!! Произошло чудо!!!! :)

Comment: Хах, можно и так сказать!)

Comment: А вы могли бы разъяснить? Почему с использованием обычного массива возникает такая ошибка? Это особенность среды VS?

Comment: @Jane_Brown: Это особенность "среды GCC". В языке С++ нет и никогда не было возможности объявлять массивы так, как это сделали вы в своем коде.